# Compass and straightedge construction of Poncelet polygons

Tags: galois-theory, geometric-construction

Gauss–Wantzel theorem states that

A regular n-gon is constructible with straightedge and compass if and only if $n = 2^kp_1p_2...p_t$, where $p_i$'s are distinct Fermat primes (A *Fermat prime* is a prime number of the form $2^{m}+1$).

A *Poncelet polygon* (or *bicentric polygon*) is a polygon which is simultaneously inscribed (all vertices lie on the same circle) and circumscribed (all sides are tangent to the same circle).

[Poncelet 4-gon and 6-gon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qHl6.png)

Such polygons play the main role in Poncelet's closure theorem (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PonceletsPorism.html). Obviously, each regular polygon is a Poncelet polygon.

**My question is**: for which $n$ it is possible to construct a non-regular Poncelet n-gon with compass and straightedge?

I know an explicit construction for $n=2^k,3 \cdot 2^k, 5 \cdot 2^k$.

**Remark.** For each $n$ there is a relation between $R$ (radius of circumcircle), $r$ (radius of incircle) and $d$ (distance between incenter and circumcenter). For $n=3$ we have Euler formula, for $n=4$ we have Fuss formula, etc (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PonceletsPorism.html). So if we put $d=1$, the question is to find constructible numbers $R$ and $r$ satisfying the relation.